# How can I create an index with pymongo

Tags: mongodb, indexing, pymongo, fuzzy-search, text-search

I want to enable text-search at a specific field in my Mongo DB. I want to implement this search in python (-> pymongo). When I follow the instructions given in the internet:

```
db.foo.ensure_index(('field_i_want_to_index', 'text'), name="search_index")
```

I get the following error message:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "CVE_search.py", line 8, in <module>
    db.foo.ensure_index(('field_i_want_to_index', 'text'), name="search_index")
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 1599, in ensure_index
        return self.create_index(key_or_list, cache_for, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 1466, in create_index
        index_doc = helpers._index_document(keys)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/helpers.py", line 100, in _index_document
            for (key, value) in index_list:
    ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Is there a different/better way to create an index in pymongo?

Comment: Linked question isn't exactly the same and has no useful answers and a dead link comment. Answer here is useful and has relevant documentation link.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use the **[`create_index`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.create_index)** method where you pass in the keys as an array and **[`TEXT`](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.TEXT)** as the index direction :

```
collection.create_index([('field_i_want_to_index', pymongo.TEXT)], name='search_index', default_language='english')
```

Comment: when I use the db.command('text', 'foo', search=query) to search the index, how can I query several words?

Comment: @PeterFox Good question but I would suggest you create a new question for that then we can take it from there.

Comment: How do we ensure that the index is unique? Where can we pass that index type is unique?