# Getting TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, flask, pymongo

so i want to use `$text` method after `$nearSphere` method in pymongo but for that i am getting this error: **TypeError: if no direction is specified, key_or_list must be an instance of list**. what is wrong here ??

```
@app.route('/connect', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def connect():
    database = mongo.db.mylogin
    mongo.db.mylogin.create_index([("location", pymongo.GEOSPHERE )])
    request_books = database.find({ "location": { "$nearSphere": { "$geometry" : {"type" : "Point",  "coordinates": [session['lang'], session['lat']]}, "$minDistance": 0,  "$maxDistance" : 5000 } } })

    mongo.db.mylogin.create_index( { "name": "text", "description": "text" } )

    search = database.find_one({ "$text": {"$search" : "biology book"}})

    return str(search)
```

Comment: check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33541637/2282634